# Python Itemgetter 'string index out of range'

Tags: python, csv, indexing, range

The code below is the one that I'm using to sort and print a csv file. There are 8 columns and I want to sort by the 7th column which is an integer. I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Task 3.py", line 271, in <module>
    sort = sorted(file, key=operator.itemgetter(6), reverse=False)
  IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is the block of code that I have used for this:

```
file = open("class1.csv", "r")
sort = sorted(file, key=operator.itemgetter(7), reverse=False)
for eachline in sort:
    print (eachline.replace("\n", ""))
file.close()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The string index error you're getting is because using `key=operator.itemgetter(7)` with `sorted()` results in it trying to sort based on the 8<sup>th</sup> character rather than that column of each row of data in the csv file.

You can fix that by first splitting each row by the `,` field delimiter character with something like this:

```
row.split(',')
```

To simplify applying these two operations, one after the other, to each line, they can be combined together with `lambda` into a composite function. In the code below the `operator.itemgetter(7)` used in your code has been replaced with a call to a new custom `itemgetter`-like function:

```
def csv_itemgetter(index, delimiter=','):
    composite = lambda row: row.split(delimiter)[index]
    return composite

with open("class1.csv") as file:
    for eachline in sorted(file, key=csv_itemgetter(7)):
        print eachline,
```

If there's the possibility that some of the rows in the file will have fewer than 8 columns, you can easily add error handling to the custom `itemgetter` that deals with them:

```
def csv_itemgetter(index, delimiter=',', default=''):
    def composite(row):
        try:
            return row.split(delimiter)[index]
        except IndexError:
            return default
    return composite
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because `operator.itemgetter(7)` is accessing the 8th *character* of the row, not the 8th *column*.

You need to parse the csv into columns first:

```
import csv

with open("class1.csv") as f:
    # since you sort the data, we may as well read everything at once
    data = list(csv.reader(f))  

sort = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(7), reverse=False)
for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline.replace("\n", ""))
```

However, this may still not work, if some of your rows have fewer than 8 columns. You can fix that with:

```
with open("class1.csv") as f:
    # ensure at least 8 columns, by appending emptystrings
    data = [
        row + [''] * (8 - len(row))
        for row in csv.reader(f))
    ]
```